# Pandas: Compare column with datetime value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date1 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-1-1 12:00:00',periods = 2, freq='M'))
date2 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2019-3-11 21:45:00',periods = 2, freq='W'))

date_df =pd.DataFrame(dict(Start_date = date1, End_date = date2))
date_df['hour'] = date_df['End_date'].dt.time
date_df
```

Returns this dataframe:

```
       Start_date             End_date           hour

0   2018-01-31 12:00:00  2019-03-17 21:45:00    21:45:00
1   2018-02-28 12:00:00  2019-03-24 21:45:00    21:45:00
```

I tried the following code:

```
def new (date_df):
if(date_df[hour] < datetime.time(hour=21, minute=46, second=0))
    return 1
else:
    return 0

date_df['NewColumn']=date_df.apply(new,axis=1)
```

Returns an error

```
File "<ipython-input-263-d67d4f9334fd>", line 2
    if(date_df[hour] < datetime.time(hour=21, minute=46, second=0))
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was trying to use this method because is more readable for my specific work.

How shoul i change the code?

Comment: There's a colon (`:`) missing after your if statement. Also your `date_df[hour]` should have quotes like this: `date_df['hour']`

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing few things here. **First**, you may want to use

```
from datetime import datetime, time
```

(emphasis on the time)

**Second**, use lambda such that:

```
date_df['NewColumn']=date_df.apply(lambda x: new(x['hour']),axis=1)
```

**Third**, your function: look at the argument hour and the time

```
def new(hour):
    if(hour < time(hour=21, minute=46, second=0)):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

result:

```
    Start_date  End_date                    hour        NewColumn
0   2018-01-31 12:00:00 2019-03-17 21:45:00 21:45:00    1
1   2018-02-28 12:00:00 2019-03-24 21:45:00 21:45:00    1
```

**Side note:**  use a proper function name and refrain from using new (it is totally legit here but in other languages its a keyword)